# Issue with OpenCart module - CodeManager

Tags: module, opencart

I have issues with one OpenCart module called [CodeManager](https://isenselabs.com/products/view/codemanager-web-based-ide-framework-for-opencart). I tried installing it several times but every time I get these warnings:

```
Warning: include(/home/johnsimo/public_html/vendors/codemanager/languages/Array.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/sdcom/public_html/game/vendors/codemanager/common.php on line 93

Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/home/johnsimo/public_html/vendors/codemanager/languages/Array.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/sdcom/public_html/game/vendors/codemanager/common.php on line 93
```

Anybody has any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: go to admin panel: system=>user groups> (**there should be some check boxes. I have used opencart few years ago so i'm not sure what exactly u will find there. I guess there will be two groups of check boxes. Under those two groups you may find something like "codemanager" check them and then try again.)

Comment: Did You ask for support the module developer?

Answer (score 0):

Basically its saying your missing some files from the extension try reinstalling if that doesnt work contact the person you got it off and get a working copy

Answer (score 0):

please try again to re install this process. or give them to file permission access. may be problem could be there.